# Installing Caffe in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, compiling, caffe

I need help building Caffe (deep learning) on Ubuntu 14.04. After running the command `sudo make all -j4` i get report like this:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/arena.h:48:0,
                 from .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:23,
                 from ./include/caffe/util/signal_handler.h:4,
                 from src/caffe/util/signal_handler.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/typeinfo:39:37: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
 #pragma GCC visibility push(default)
                                     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/typeinfo:39:37: error: expected unqualified-id before end of line
/usr/include/c++/4.8/typeinfo:39:37: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
/usr/include/c++/4.8/typeinfo:39:37: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
/usr/include/c++/4.8/typeinfo:39:37: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
/usr/include/c++/4.8/typeinfo:39:37: error: expected declaration before end of line
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/util/signal_handler.o] Error 1
```

What does this error mean? Here are the [instructions I've used to build](https://gist.github.com/nikitametha/c54e1abecff7ab53896270509da80215) Caffe:
Because i am new in Linux OS, i will be happy for every suggestion to solve my error  :)

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade your Ubuntu? 14.04 is quite old now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see any messages about `c++11` or `gnu++11`?

Looks like a similar problem is here: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6359

Solutions are

1. Updating protobuf and adding the following to the MAKEFILE:

   ```
   CXXFLAGs += -std=c++11
   ```

   Not sure if these flags are required in the MAKEFILE (try them if the above doesn't work):

   ```
   NVCCFLAGS += -std=c++11
   CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
   LINKFLAGS += -std=c++11
   ```
2. Use an older protobuf (2.x) which is c++ 98 compatible